Could not find any file matching the template file pattern
I am migrating the classic release pipeline to the YML Pipeline.
Note: The build pipeline is already a YML pipeline.
Post writing the yml and running the jobs getting below error for azure deployment task:
Could not find any file matching the template file pattern
And also please let me know what we need to use in this case, is it System.DefaultWorkingDirectory (or) System.ArtifactsDirectory (or) Pipeline.Workspace
            - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
      displayName: 'Deploy to ARM Template'
      inputs:
        azureResourceManagerConnection: 'Transportation-SPN'
        subscriptionId: 'c0779592-f81d-4971-8210-11b7eb2b4521'
        resourceGroupName: '$(ResourceGroupName)'
        location: 'West US 2'
        csmFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/deployment/azuredeploy.json'
        overrideParameters: '-gcsAppInsightsName $(GcsAppInsightsName) -shouldCreateGCSAppInsights $(ShouldCreateGCSAppInsights)  -azureMapAccountName $(AzureMapAccountName) -cdnContainerName $(CdnContainerName) -azureMapPricingTier $(AzureMapPricingTier) -shouldDeployAzureMap $(ShouldDeployAzureMap) -keyVaultName $(KeyVaultName) -shouldDeployKeyVault $(ShouldDeployKeyVault) -deploymentAgentObjectId $(DeploymentAgentObjectId) -thubEngTeamObjectId $(ThubEngTeamObjectId) -shouldPerformKVRoleAssignments $(shouldPerformKVRoleAssignments) -azureFrontDoorCdnObjectId $(azureFrontDoorCdnObjectId)'
        deploymentOutputs: AzureMapsKey


Are you using AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3 in a deployment job? have - checkout: self been added ?

Update
Based on the further discussions, if your deployment scripts and templates are under the deployment folder in the repo root directory like that in the image below,

Please note that the default first step of a traditional job is to checkout: self. If you are running AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3 in a deployment job, you will need to add the checkout: self step in front to retrieve the templates, because the default first step of a deployment job is to download published artifacts rather than checkout code from the repo. If you didn't change the checkout path but only used check: self, the template path should be $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/deployment/azuredeploy.json no matter in job or deployment.
jobs:
- job: TraditionalJob
  pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
  - script: |
      # For ubuntu agent
      tree $(Pipeline.Workspace)
    displayName: Check path
  - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
    inputs:
      deploymentScope: 'Subscription'
      azureResourceManagerConnection: 'ARMSvcCnnWIFSub0'
      subscriptionId: '$(subId)'
      location: 'Central US'
      templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
      csmFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/deployment/azuredeploy.json'
      deploymentMode: 'Validation'

- deployment: DeploymentJob
  pool:
    vmImage: windows-latest
  environment: E-test
  strategy:
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
        - checkout: self
        - script: |
            # For windows agent
            tree $(Pipeline.Workspace) /f /a
          displayName: Check path
        - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
          inputs:
            deploymentScope: 'Subscription'
            azureResourceManagerConnection: 'ARMSvcCnnWIFSub0'
            subscriptionId: '$(subId)'
            location: 'Central US'
            templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
            csmFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/deployment/azuredeploy.json'
            deploymentMode: 'Validation'


You haven't shared where your templates are stored and how your file structure is. Let's assume your pipeline was retrieving templates from your repo rather than the artifacts published by any build pipeline.
Taking my repo file structure below for example, if the azuredeploy.json file was located in the root directory of the repo and by default, the template file would be checked out into $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) on the agent machine during this YAML pipeline build.

You may also consider running tree $(Pipeline.Workspace) command on ubuntu-latest or tree $(Pipeline.Workspace) /f /a command on windows-latest Microsoft-hosted agent to check the file structure on the agent machine.
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: |
    # For ubuntu agent
    tree $(Pipeline.Workspace)
    # For windows agent
    # tree $(Pipeline.Workspace) /f /a
  displayName: Check path



I am in the process of migratin classic release to yml and the deploy scripts are under the deployment folder under repo.
Do we need to use self checkout or use the System.DefaultWorkingDirectory (or) System.ArtifactsDirectory (or) Pipeline.Workspace

Thanks for the update. The default first step of a traditional job is checkout: self. If you are running AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3 in a deployment job, you will need to add the checkout: self step in front in order to retrieve the templates, because the default first step of a deployment job is to download: current published artifacts.

If we run check: self task in a YAML build pipeline to retrieve the templates from the repo, the template path should be $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/deployment/azuredeploy.json no matter in job or deployment.

Now the issue is resolved , i have included the reference to take artifacts from build pipeline with beliw syntax in additon to add the check: self
csmFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/${{ parameters.BuildPipelineName }}/DeployScripts/azuredeploy.json'

Hi #Nagarjun, Glad to know the issue is resolved. But do you mean the template is from your repo or the published artifacts? If they are from the artifacts published by another pipeline, you don't need to check: self I guess.
